# Use JavaScript to add a Class to the <html> element respective to the browser

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I kind of know how Modernizr works, by adding a Class to the `<html>` element, I know that  jQuery Browser Detection is deprecated, is there a way to detect and add a class ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @tjameson: I could see it being useful for hacking around CSS bugs in non-IE browsers.

Comment: @mu is too short - Adding a class to <html> is useful? I could see throwing out a console.log or something, but the <html> tag doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @tjameson: But it will be there and you allow you to `.fix-stupid-bug .normal-css { ... }` to kludge around CSS bugs. But `<body>` would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting a browser is not difficult (though generally not recommended and occasionally inaccurate).  If you're familiar with modernizr, then you should know that feature detection is much more maintainable and accurate mechanism for identifying which behavior you should use in the host browser.  For actual browser detection (again, not recommended), I'd suggest reading this Mozilla article: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Browser_Detection_and_Cross_Browser_Support.

For setting a class, that's much easier.  To set a class on the body object, you would just do this:

```
document.body.className = "xxxx";
```

or to add a class, you would use this:

```
document.body.className += " xxxxx";
```

Comment: I resort to Browser Detection, due to Browser-Differences, in FireFox and Chrome, I don't have to worry about [IE](http://goo.gl/fDzNl)

Comment: Do you understand how "feature detection" or "feature behavior detection" like modernizr does can almost always give you the answers you need for your code to adapt to the host browser, but it's safer and easier and more maintainable than looking for specific browser versions?

Comment: The only reason I want it is to detect the OS (Windows) and add font smoothing to it ( text-shadow ) because browsers that have Font Smoothing Enabled look weird with Text Shadow font smoothing

Comment: @Rigel Glen - For the future, if you had included that info about font smoothing in the original question, your answers/comments would have been much more focused on helping you with that issue.